# Generation of 3-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I want to generate a 3-D array by assigning an array to an array.
Following are codes written by me.

```
import numpy as np
    def func01(a):
        b = np.array([[a, 3],
                      [4, 5]])
        return b
    
    a = np.array([1, 2]) 
    b = func01(a)
    print(b)
```

Originally, I wrote this code expecting the following output.

```
    [[[1 3]
      [4 5]]
     [[2 3]
      [4 5]]]
```

However, the following output is obtained.

```
    [[array([1, 2]) 3]
     [4 5]]
```

Could someone give me a solution?

My goal is to curve fit a function involving matrix calculation by SciPy.
I want to perform the curve fit for following function.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

def func01(A, k):
    b1 = np.array([[A[0], 3],
                  [4, 5]])
    b2 = np.array([[A[1], 3],
                  [4, 5]])

    B = np.dot(b1, b2)    
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(B)
    C = w[np.argmax(w)] * k
    
    return C

x = np.array([173, 273, 373]) 
y = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
xy = np.append([x],[y],axis=0)
z = np.array([0.023, 0.027, 0.031])
k =0.00005 # initial value
para_opt, cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func01, xy, z, k)
print(para_opt[0])
```

I can get the value with a simple variable assignment in this function.

```
k = 0.0005
A = np.array([1,2])
C = func01(A, k)
print(C)
```

However, I cannot perform the curve fit with SciPy.
When I used the SciPy, the following values were assigned to b1 above.

```
[[array([173., 273., 373.]) 3]
 [4 5]]
```

Therefore, I wanted to know how to get the following matrix.

```
[[[173 3]
  [4 5]]
 [[173 3]
  [4 5]]]
 [[173 3]
  [4 5]]]
```

Comment: can you describe your goal? There are multiple ways to achieve what you want, but it's hard to recommend any of them without seeing the bigger picture

Comment: This looks like you expected broadcasting behavior to increase dimensions, and while that works with many operators and SciPy functions, it doesn't work with index assignment. There's probably some elegant functions for this, but the simplest thing is to build an array with your desired dimensions and assign the smaller arrays to slices of it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. My goal is to curve fit a function involving matrix calculation by Scipy. I added a supplement to the main text. If you know a solution, could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [210]: res = np.zeros((2,2,2),int)                                                                
In [211]: res[:] = np.array([[0,3],[4,5]])                                                           
In [212]: res                                                                                        
Out[212]: 
array([[[0, 3],
        [4, 5]],

       [[0, 3],
        [4, 5]]])
In [213]: res[:,0,0]=[1,2]                                                                           
In [214]: res                                                                                        
Out[214]: 
array([[[1, 3],
        [4, 5]],

       [[2, 3],
        [4, 5]]])
```

Tell us about `curve_fit`.  What does it expect with regards to the arguments - type and shape?  Do your arguments fit?  As written your function expects `A` to have shape (2,).  Is that what you are getting?  Why, or why not?

(I could look up `curve_fit` docs, but I'd rather you did some that leg work.  You need the debugging practice :)

### your curve_fit problem - with column iteration

So your arrays are:

```
In [216]: xy                                                                                         
Out[216]: 
array([[1.73e+02, 2.73e+02, 3.73e+02],
       [1.00e-01, 2.00e-01, 3.00e-01]])
In [217]: z                                                                                          
Out[217]: array([0.023, 0.027, 0.031])
```

And apparently you want to call `func01` with one column of `xy`:

```
In [219]: func01(xy[:,0],.00005)                                                                     
Out[219]: 0.00687966968797453
```

to work with all columns we can start with an straight forward iteration:

```
In [220]: def foo(A,k): 
     ...:     return np.array([func01(A[:,i],k) for i in range(A.shape[1])]) 

In [222]: foo(xy,.00005)                                                                             
Out[222]: array([0.00687967, 0.00921688, 0.0120737 ])
```

And using that in `curve_fit`:

```
In [223]: k =0.00005 # initial value     
In [226]: optimize.curve_fit(foo, xy, z, k)                                                          
Out[226]: (array([0.00014051]), array([[1.04449717e-10]]))
```

A further step is to modify the function so it works with 2d `xy` without that iteration.  But for a start we need a clear working example.  It's always easier to improve working code that we can check our answers against.

### vectorizing func (part 1)

Now that we have reference we can try to "vectorize" the function - step by step.  We need to do more than generate a 3d array, I think.

Looks like the `b1.dot(b2)` and following needs to be a "batched" operation, so lets use `@`:

```
In [228]: def func02(A, k): 
     ...:     bb = np.zeros((2,A.shape[1],2,2)) 
     ...:     for i in range(A.shape[1]): 
     ...:         bb[0,i] = np.array([[A[0,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:         bb[1,i] = np.array([[A[1,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:  
     ...:     #B = np.dot(b1, b2) 
     ...:     B = bb[0] @ bb[1]     
     ...:     w, v = np.linalg.eig(B) 
     ...:     C = w[np.argmax(w, axis=-1)] * k 
     ...:     return C 
     ...:                                                                                            

In [230]: func02(xy,.00005)                                                                          
Out[230]: 
array([[ 0.00921688, -0.00403688],
       [-0.00356467,  0.00687967],
       [-0.00356467,  0.00687967]])
```

Not right.  Let's a shape print:

```
In [231]: def func02(A, k): 
     ...:     bb = np.zeros((2,A.shape[1],2,2)) 
     ...:     for i in range(A.shape[1]): 
     ...:         bb[0,i] = np.array([[A[0,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:         bb[1,i] = np.array([[A[1,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:  
     ...:     #B = np.dot(b1, b2) 
     ...:     B = bb[0] @ bb[1]     
     ...:     w, v = np.linalg.eig(B) 
     ...:     print(B.shape, w.shape) 
     ...:     C = w[np.argmax(w, axis=-1)] * k 
     ...:     return C 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                            
In [232]:                                                                                            
In [232]: func02(xy,.00005)                                                                          
(3, 2, 2) (3, 2)
Out[232]: 
array([[ 0.00921688, -0.00403688],
       [-0.00356467,  0.00687967],
       [-0.00356467,  0.00687967]])
```

The `w` indexing needs tweaking:

```
In [233]: def func02(A, k): 
     ...:     bb = np.zeros((2,A.shape[1],2,2)) 
     ...:     for i in range(A.shape[1]): 
     ...:         bb[0,i] = np.array([[A[0,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:         bb[1,i] = np.array([[A[1,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:  
     ...:     #B = np.dot(b1, b2) 
     ...:     B = bb[0] @ bb[1]     
     ...:     w, v = np.linalg.eig(B) 
     ...:     print(B.shape, w.shape) 
     ...:     C = w[:, np.argmax(w, axis=-1)] * k 
     ...:     return C 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                            
In [234]: func02(xy,.00005)                                                                          
(3, 2, 2) (3, 2)
Out[234]: 
array([[ 0.00687967, -0.00356467, -0.00356467],
       [-0.00403688,  0.00921688,  0.00921688],
       [-0.0040287 ,  0.0120737 ,  0.0120737 ]])
```

The correct values  are on the diagonal, so we need another change to the indexing:

```
In [235]: def func02(A, k): 
     ...:     n = A.shape[1] 
     ...:     bb = np.zeros((2,n,2,2)) 
     ...:     for i in range(n): 
     ...:         bb[0,i] = np.array([[A[0,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:         bb[1,i] = np.array([[A[1,i], 3], 
     ...:                   [4, 5]]) 
     ...:  
     ...:     #B = np.dot(b1, b2) 
     ...:     B = bb[0] @ bb[1]     
     ...:     w, v = np.linalg.eig(B) 
     ...:     print(B.shape, w.shape) 
     ...:     C = w[np.arange(n), np.argmax(w, axis=-1)] * k 
     ...:     return C 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                            
In [236]: func02(xy,.00005)                                                                          
(3, 2, 2) (3, 2)
Out[236]: array([0.00687967, 0.00921688, 0.0120737 ])
```

That matches `foo`.  So works in the curvefit:

```
In [237]: optimize.curve_fit(func02, xy, z, k)                                                       
(3, 2, 2) (3, 2)
...
(3, 2, 2) (3, 2)
Out[237]: (array([0.00014051]), array([[1.04449717e-10]]))
```

Now that we have the last part of `func02` right, we can address your original 3d array issue.

### final

Using the array construction I started with:

```
In [240]: def func02(A, k): 
     ...:     n = A.shape[1] 
     ...:     bb = np.zeros((2,n,2,2)) 
     ...:     bb[:] = np.array([[0,3],[4,5]]) 
     ...:     bb[:,:,0,0] = A 
     ...:     B = bb[0] @ bb[1]     
     ...:     w, v = np.linalg.eig(B) 
     ...:     C = w[np.arange(n), np.argmax(w, axis=-1)] * k 
     ...:     return C 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [241]: func02(xy,.00005)                                                                          
Out[241]: array([0.00687967, 0.00921688, 0.0120737 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

```
def func01(a):
    n = len(a)
    b = np.tile(np.array([[0, 3], [4, 5]]), (n,1)).reshape(-1,2,2)
    b[:,0,0] = a
    return b
```

It gives proper results regardless of the length of *a*.
Furthermore, *a* can be either a *list* or a 1-D *Numpy* array.

To test this function, run:

```
a = np.array([11, 12, 13])
func01(a)
```

getting:

```
array([[[11,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[12,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[13,  3],
        [ 4,  5]]])
```